# for single digit numric value elements, couldnt find the duplicates in jQuery

Tags: jquery

To find the duplicates, this is my extended function.

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.expr[":"],{
    duplicateValues:function(element){
        var return_val = false;
        jQuery(element).each(function(){
             if(jQuery(element+"[value='"+jQuery(this).val()+"']").length > 1){
                return_val = true;
                return false;
             }   
        });
        return return_val;
    }
});
```

and this is called as

```
if(jQuery('.option_text:duplicateValues').length > 0){
    alert("Duplicate in answer options");
    return false;
}
```

This is working fine for all alpha numeric and strings. If only single numeric value is given in the text box, without any duplication, it is showing the alert for duplication.

it is working fine for the single characters too.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure? i tested it with this markup (http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/dg9BE/1/):

```
<input type='text' value='1' class='option_text'/>
<input type='text' value='2' class='option_text'/>
<input type='text' value='3' class='option_text'/>
```

an this markup (http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/dg9BE/2/)

```
<input type='text' value='1' class='option_text'/>
```

And it was correct

Comment: Yes Nicola, it is working fine when I have given this elements separately. I forgot to say, those elements I referred via class names are built dynamically. Will it make any problem.

Comment: What do you mean?Can you provide an example on jsfiddle?

Comment: In the end I came to see that the following line in my code,`if(jQuery(element+"[value='"+jQuery(this).val()+"']").length > 1)`, there the selectors referring all the elements in the document,instead of searching the ".option_text" class elements. I had some elements having the values from 1 to 9. So the count is getting greater than 1 always.... Thanks for your time and Support.